# Laravel 5.4.28 gives "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting the error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from users where 1)

from any query I attempt to send to my database.

Running `php artisan migrate` runs completely fine from command line showing that my settings are correct! Whats going wrong?!

**.env:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vehiclexray
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=kzurxsxz1
```

**database.php:**

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
     'prefix' => '',
     'strict' => true,
     'engine' => 
]
```

Comment: You've shown the MySQL config, but is it selected?  You need to specify to use that, in database.php, eg `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')`, do you have that?

Comment: Yeah its selected. I've fixed it now by changing to another database